# Can application of external force cancel off the emf induced due to external magnetic field in a charged conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

If we take a charged conductor in a time-varying magnetic field and apply a varying force on it so that the Lorentz force on it is cancelled by the varying force, will an emf still be induced on the material?

Comment: I replaced the word 'material' with 'conductor' and I also have changed your title. If my changes are incorrect, then kindly roll them back.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, yes.

The EMF will be induced for as long as the magnetic flux varies, which in this case is, for as long as the magnetic field varies, since the area is kept constant. The only thing that the external variable force would really do, is keep the conductor from performing accelerated motion.